# Excon::Errors::BadRequest RoR Tutorial Hartl 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, railstutorial.org, fog

Im reading and following M.Harls "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" and im stucked at introducing AWS. I got this error: 
[Server logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef8Qh.png)

7 line in micropost controller is "if @micropost.save", so it's not saved obviously.
I use CarrierWave and fog, like Hartl described. Here my CarrierWave config:

```
if Rails.env.production?
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.fog_credentials = {
  # Configuration for Amazon S3
  :provider              => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
  :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
  :region                 => ENV['S3_REGION'] 
}
config.fog_directory     =  ENV['S3_BUCKET']
end
end
```

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: The body of the error has a `message` field that is cut out in that image. Could you share just the text version of that part of the log, instead of an image? I think that would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @geemus
 I cut this line, i know this important, but i cut cuz of some info, that was stupid: 
at=info method=POST path="/microposts" host=my-host.app.heroku.com request_id=6c75d08e-5342-49fe-b7e3-5bf1fcfa33d0 fwd="151.0.51.102" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2227ms status=500 bytes=1714

Comment: Ah. The part in particular that I could use more info on is the piece that follows where it says `excon.error.response`. Could you share that?

Comment: @geemus Here the error:
"The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256."
I find out that i use old V2 authorization mechanism, which not supported by actually new Frankfurt server. How can i fix it, instead of changing the server?

Comment: Ah, that does narrow it down. I think the new signature is used by default with newer versions of fog, are you updated to the latest version?

Comment: @geemus Now i do, but nothing changes, the error is the same
the latest version is 1.37.0, right?

Comment: Yes, though these changes will be within `fog-aws`, so you may need to update that as well (latest for that is 0.9.1).

Comment: @geemus oh, it works now! Thanks a lot. I dont have even earlier versions of fog-aws installed, but now i do. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it!